# In AppleScript when entering password, is a click required

Tags: macos, applescript, password

I'm writing an AppleScript to toggle on/off a VPN connection for a computer.

I have things more or less working, however, I have to click on the password prompt dialog in order for the script to enter my password.

Here is the code block to put the password in, I added the `reopen` and `activate` commands because I *thought* they would bring the window to focus.

```
-- Enter the password now!
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        reopen
        activate
        set value of text field 2 of window 1 to myPass
        click button 2 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Is there something simple I'm missing?

---

#### UPDATE

Ok Update - Actually it looks like it IS entering the password but its after maybe a 6 second delay or something like that.  I'm no sure if that changes the question

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your code:

```
set first responder to text field 2 of window 1
```

This should bring focus to the text field.

For reference, see this post on [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=18814)

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SecurityAgent" to ¬
set frontmost to true
```